# Applescript copy newer files based on file dates

Tags: macos, applescript

I haven't seen this specific answer, especially when it comes to copying a file based on dates (e.g. Not copying the same file twice) and running the script, say, once an hour.

And, I'm an AppleScript newbie. So, the code is probably full of errors. But, you get the idea of what I'm going for:

```
on idle
    Tell application "Finder"

    set a to folder ":Volumes:G_Drive Mini:source"
    set b to folder ":Volumes:MarkCapsule:destination"
    if dateOfFile > currentDate then
        move file of a to b
    end if
    return 3600

    end tell
end idle
```

I don't have any idea of how `if dateOfFile < currentDate then` works. The rest I can, I think, figure out.

Can anyone offer assistance?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with two variables that contain a date.

The script copies the files whose date of creation is between these two dates.

The range between these two dates will always be about an hour, but no range when the script run for the first time, because the difference between these dates will be only a few seconds.

```
property a : "Volumes:G_Drive Mini:source" as alias
property b : "Volumes:MarkCapsule:destination" as alias
property lastCopy : current date

on idle
    set currDate to current date
    with timeout of 500 seconds
        tell application "Finder" to ¬
            move (files of a whose creation date < currDate and creation date ≥ lastCopy) to b
    end timeout
    copy currDate to lastCopy
    return 3600
end idle
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to change the name of the variable in this line and `set lastCopy to currentDate` line

Comment: Thanks! It works right out of the box. I'm studying it because I want to know more about what it does.